# SKLabelNode.color vs SKLabelNode.fontColor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

What is the difference between `SKLabelNode.color` and `SKLabelNode.fontColor`? I already know how to use `SKLabelNode`, and I do not want any answers stating how to use the `SKLabelNode`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious - why don't you put a label on screen with .color = SKColor.red and .fontColor = SKColor.green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains what they are:

```
    /**
     Base color that the text is rendered with (if supported by the font)
     */
    open var fontColor: UIColor?


    /**
     Controls the blending between the rendered text and a color. The valid interval of values is from 0.0 up to and including 1.0. A value above or below that interval is clamped to the minimum (0.0) if below or the maximum (1.0) if above.
     */
    open var colorBlendFactor: CGFloat


    /**
     Color to be blended with the text based on the colorBlendFactor
     */
    open var color: UIColor?
```

Here is an example to help better understand how it works:

```
    let label1 = SKLabelNode(text: "Red")
    label1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
    label1.fontColor = .red
    addChild(label1)

    let label2 = SKLabelNode(text: "Red")
    label2.color = .red
    label2.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    addChild(label2)

    let label3 = SKLabelNode(text: "Dull Red")
    label3.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
    label3.color = .red
    label3.colorBlendFactor = 0.5
    addChild(label3)

    let label4 = SKLabelNode(text: "White")
    label4.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100)
    label4.color = .red
    label4.colorBlendFactor = 0.0
    addChild(label4)
```

By default all labels are white which comes into play when using colorBlendFactor. `label1` and `label2` are the same red color. `label1` is red because it's font color is set to red. `label2` is red because red is blending with its white color at a factor of 1.0. As the label's colorBlendFactor nears 0 it'll get more and more white as seen in `label3` and `label4`.